# PhpStorm - moving run/debug pane

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.1

My PhpStorm Run/Debug pane was somehow moved at the right side of the screen and I can't find a way to put it back. It's supposed to be on the left side. I tried "Restore default layout", didn't work. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: I guess you need to put it to different row, that should fix the problem, but at the moment I can't verify it

Comment: How do I put it in a different row? it's not draggable, right click does nothing, I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in Android Studio and it should be the same for PhpStorm: turn on Toolbar in View menu.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!